# Unable to see all folders on Moto G using FTP

Tags: linux, motorola-moto-g, ftp

I have set up an FTP server on my Moto G, and I'm trying to copy (music) files from my laptop (running Ubuntu 12.04) using FileZilla.

I understand that user data appears in the `/data` folder, but when I try to open this folder, FileZilla says

```
Response:   150 Directory listing for data/
Response:   550 Requested action not taken.  does not exist, not a directory or insufficient rights
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

Comment: Is your phone rooted?

Comment: @eldarerathis No, it isn't.

Comment: You won't be able to index `/data` without root, but you shouldn't need it to copy music over anyway. Can you access an `/sdcard` or `/storage/emulated` location via the FTP server?

Comment: Thanks. I'm now able to access the Music folder through Filezilla. Though I wonder why it keeps getting disconnected every time I try to transfer one or more files. It takes a long time to start up also. The network I am on is pretty fast but.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem, but I launched filezilla from Terminal using `sudo`:

```
sudo filezilla
```

It works fine.

Comment: What's the point of launching it via terminal?

Comment: You need not launch using terminal, u need to launch it through root user or administrator in windows. Terminal is the convenient for me to do.